# Красивая анимция входа в окно настроек

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня на сцене имеется два канваса, один активен, другой - нет. Скрипт при нажатии на кнопку вырубает один канвас, врубает другой. Это мой механизм входа в меню настроек. Я хочу наложить какую-то анимацию свайпа, еще что-либо. Как это можно реализовать? Я просто даже не представляю.

Comment: делается так же, как и обычная анимация. почитай/посмотри про них материал

Comment: можешь дать ссылку на материал, пожалуйста?

Comment: посмотри примеры анимации тут [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtLx-hVWNL0)
непонятно зачем два канваса, если можно объединить в один объект-панельку например и уже работать с ней. вот еще не самый качественный, но вроде понятный урок по анимации [урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwbpaR3AIrI)
посмотри еще такой видос, не по теме конечно, но там тоже полезно может быть [видос](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfO11O4pUp8)

Comment: спасибо большое!